# I want to get the path to jdk to set JAVA_HOME in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, path, java-home

I want to run a jar file on a ubuntu server without writing the full path. Therefore, I would like to edit the .zshrc. I would appreciate it if you could tell us how to set JAVA_HOME and PATH.

I am currently trying that with reference to this web site, but have been unsuccessful because I don't know how to get the path to the jdk. I am having trouble.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/b2b-integrator/6.0.1?topic=variables-setting-java-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# The next var an example path obvs.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java16-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You might like to look at `update-java-alternatives` though

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
How do I know what JAVA_HOME should be set to in my case?

I wrote "which java" but could not know it.

Comment: You should see that with `readlink -f $(which java)`
Why do you think you need to set JAVA_HOME btw?
Iust to be clear the value for JAVA_HOME would be the directory that contains bin normally. You should probably tell use what value you get from `readlink`

Comment: I have a file called trimmomatic.jar running on my ubuntu server. But to do that I have to write `java -jar ~anaconda3/share/trimmomatic-0.39-2/trimmomatic.jar`. I want to just write `java -jar trimmomatic.jar` to execute the file.

Comment: That's not relevant to our discussion I'm afraid. The variables will have no bearing on the path to the jar

Comment: It was. So when we run the jar file, do we have to write the full path?

Comment: Effectively yes. Obviously you could have a launcher or a script that would contain the path

Comment: The question has been answered. Thank you so much for your help. I will now learn more about launchers.